# Tapping on Table cell, view should come only in present view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am developing an app with Slide out & side-bar menu, when i go to rearview a table appears. On tapping table cells the next view should appear only in the present view (just like the rearview on the top of frontview).

[image: story board layout]

Comment: whats ur question...?

Comment: question is on tapping the table items the next view should appear in the same view(just like the rearview) @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: ok where u struck and what the answer u need for this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: problem here is on tapping table cells it is moving on to whole another view. I am using SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController class for my segue. Any idea how to sort this out?